# C++ 11, how to use a const inside an #if

Tags: c++, if-statement, constants

I use a const variable in my code. And would like to tell my pre-processor to use it. Namely:

```
const double x = 1.2;
const bool xIsZero = x==0;

#if xIsZero
...
#endif
```

But that doesn't work. In C++ 17, `if constexpr` doest the trick. But I'm stuck with C++11 for now.

So instead I could use a workaround like:

```
#define X 1.2
#define xIsZero (x==0)
const double x = X;

#if xIsZero
...
#endif
```

But I just dislike giving x to a #define, I'd like to give it directly to a const. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This sounds like the perfect example of an X/Y problem. What do you want to put inside that #ifdef?  If you want to select some interface or implementation based on a compile-time (or preprocessor-time) condition, C++ has other mechanisms:  templates or `if constexpr`.  Just ask what you really want to accomplish!

Comment: You can't. Preprocessor directives are executed before the compiler even attempts to understand what the rest of the code means. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the condition is known at compile-time, you can use overloading to mimic `if constexpr` in C++11:

```
void foo(std::true_type) {   // if (xIsZero)
}

void foo(std::false_type) {  // if (!xIsZero)
}

constexpr bool xIsZero = ...;
foo(std::integral_constant<bool, xIsZero>{});
```

---

As **LoPiTaL** noted in comments, this is not fully equivalent to `if constexpr`, because both `foo`s have to compile. This technique becomes important when we work with templates. With plain `if` both branches are compiled with the same set of template parameters. With overloading we can effectively discard branches.

For example, this code fails:

```
template<unsigned int i>
void foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i>) {
    if (i > 0) {
        consume_positive_i(i);
        foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i - 1>{});
    } else
        consume_zero_i(i);
}
```

In C++17 it can easily be fixed with `if constexpr`:

```
template<unsigned int i>
void foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i>) {
    if constexpr (i > 0) {
        consume_positive_i(i);
        foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i - 1>{});
    } else
        consume_zero_i(i);
}
```

The workaround in C++11 is overloading:

```
void foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 0>) {   
    consume_zero_i(i);
}

template<unsigned int i>
void foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i>) {
    consume_positive_i(i);
    foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i - 1>{});
}
```

Comment: note that this answer does not mimic the (generic) behaviour of an `#if` or the `if constexpr`, since with this aproach both branches have to compile fine, despite the false one will be discarded in later steps.

Comment: @LoPiTaL, that's true, they are not fully equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`#if` statement is a preprocessor directive. Preprocessor works with your code before the process of compilation. Preprocessor even doesn't know what your code mean, it actually works with text. '#if' checks if argument is true (or defined) and put code into file from `#if`-`#else`-`#endif` statement.

`#define` replaces your code for selected. And when you type

```
#define X 1.2
void f() {
    if(X == 0) //...
}
```

Preprocessor replace this for the

```
void f() {
    if(1.2 == 0) //...
}
```

`const` is a keyword for compiler. Constants are defined in the time of compilation and they are put into special area in memory. So when you type

```
const double x = 1.2;
void f () {
    if(x == 0) //...
}
```

you call `x` from that memory.

So when you're trying to access with preprocessor to the area that compiler deal with, you're getting what you have.